# Toasts alongside messages in primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

Is there a way to use two messageServices in one component using primeng? My problem is that I need to display toasts and messages depending on error type in my app, and I just can't find a working solution for this.
Every time a message is added to messageService in component it is being displayed both as a message and a toast.

I tried creating two services for toast and messages like so:

```
export class ToastInformationService {

  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) { }

  pushInformation(message: string): void {
    this.messageService.add({
      detail: message
    });
  };
}
```

And then using it in a component

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  informations: string[] = [];

  constructor(
    private informationService: InformationService,
    private toastInformationsService: ToastInformationService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  sendMessage(message: string): void {
    this.informationService.pushInformation(message);
  }

  showToast(message: string): void {
    this.toastInformationsService.pushInformation(this, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Updated** to add some detail & clarity.*

It's not immediately clear from the documentation that you can achieve this but since the `Toast` and `Message` both use the `MessageService` you need to use the `key` property to indicate which component you are targeting.

From the "Targeting Messages" section of the "Toast" documentation ([Toast](https://primeng.org/toast))

> A page may have multiple toast components, in case you'd like to target a specific message to a particular toast, use the key property so that toast and the message can match.

From the "Message Service" section of the "Messages" documentation (emphasis added) [Messages](https://primeng.org/messages)

> MessageService alternative does not require a value binding to an array. In order to use this service, import the class and define it as a provider in a component higher up in the component tree such as application instance itself so that descandant components can have it injected. **If there are multiple message components having the same message service, you may use key property of the component to match the key of the message to implement scoping.**

Example:

```html
<p-toast key="myKey1"></p-toast>
<p-toast key="myKey2"></p-toast>
```

```
this.messageService.add({key: 'myKey1', severity:'success', summary: 'Summary Text', detail: 'Detail Text'});
this.messageService.add({key: 'myKey2', severity:'success', summary: 'Summary Text', detail: 'Detail Text'});
```

In your case you'd need to update your HTML and the `pushInformation(message: string):` to have a `key` parameter.

```html
<p-toast key="myToast"></p-toast>
<p-message key="myMessage"></p-toast>
```

```
this.informationService.pushInformation(message, "myToast"); // Toast
this.informationService.pushInformation(message, "myMessage"); // Message
```

```
pushInformation(message: string, key: string): void {
  this.messageService.add({
    detail: message,
    key: key
  });
};
```

Make sure you have imported the MessageService into your module etc.:

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/messages'; // p-messages component
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast'; // p-toast component
```